# Android calling to display anther Tab within a tab

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

In my appliaction I'm using TabActivity.
I'd like to change the current Tab within another tab.
That means, in my current tab i have a button which is calling to another cativity to be displyed that it located on another tab.
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: You've asked 17 questions on stackoverflow and you've never accepted a single one. You need to fix that.

Comment: Sorry instead of 17 questions, it raised to 23 questions now, What a great ratio you are maintaining, for this management you must be have MBA degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the link

[Opening the activity in another Tab on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582727/opening-the-activity-in-another-tab-on-click)

This will be fine

Comment: Does not work. tabHost does not fimiliar in the Activity which holds the button unfamiliar with tabHost.setCurrentTab(1). How can i pass the tabHost to the Activity inside the Tab?

Comment: TabActivity mainActivity = (TabActivity) getParent();
TabHost tabHost = mainActivity.getTabHost();
tabHost.setCurrentTab(Constants.MAP_TAB_INDEX);